# Why is this not converting to float using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, casting

I cannot seem to get this integer to convert to a float. Although I have it converting correctly. I keep getting 1 as the answer telling me its not converting from Integer... Why?

```
SELECT
    a.date,
     COUNT(b.user_id_receiver)/COUNT(a.user_id_sender)::float as acceptance_rate
FROM (
    SELECT 
        date,
        user_id_sender,
        user_id_receiver,
        action
    FROM fb_friend_requests
    WHERE action = 'sent') a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        date,
        user_id_sender,
        user_id_receiver,
        action
    FROM fb_friend_requests
    WHERE action = 'accepted') b 
    ON b.user_id_sender = a.user_id_sender
    AND b.user_id_receiver = b.user_id_receiver
GROUP BY a.date
```

Comment: It doesn't. The result is an integer so I tried casting it but same result.

Comment: What are the two count values?

Comment: Why not show us the actually result and you want result of the sql?

The result is a numeric, just like this

```sql
select 1/2;  --0
select 1/2::float;--0.5
```

Comment: [Works as expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/100397).

Answer (score 2):

It is working on my comp:

```
(2023-01-01 06:48:05) postgres=# select count(oid) / count(probin) from pg_proc;
┌──────────┐
│ ?column? │
╞══════════╡
│       36 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)

(2023-01-01 06:48:16) postgres=# select count(oid) / count(probin)::float from pg_proc;
┌────────────────────┐
│      ?column?      │
╞════════════════════╡
│ 36.662921348314605 │
└────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Sometimes, the cast operator has lower priority than other operator, but it is not this case.

Postgres (from historical reasons) supports integer dividing. When both sides are integer, then result is integer again. It is very different than other databases does, but it is too late to change it.